# How to launch an iPhone app non-publicly?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

Suppose I have developed an iPhone app. I have very specific clients and I want only them to use.

1. Clients can easily download / install my app and use it by giving their username and password
2. I don't want public to know
3. Clients' copies can automatically be updated if any new releases

How can I do those above? in-house app?

Comment: Enterprise Distribution, maybe?

Comment: If the number of your clients are less than 100, you could use the distribution provisioning file with all their devices added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [apples enterprise distribution program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) which will provide appropriate guidance for the solution you are looking for.

Also i suggest you to read the [FAQ list](https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.php) so that you know a bit more about the enterprise app distribution process. Finally if you are satisfied with this approach then you need to create a build and upload to your server for enterprise distribution then in that case you can check this [link](http://www.maas360.com/maasters/forums/mobile-app-management-mam/show/332/building-ios-apps-for-enterprise-deployment).

Answer (score 0):

it is possible only through Enterprise Application distribution
You can develop in-house Application for specific targeted people or clients